# Wine Dependencies Error

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dependencies

My computer crashed when I was installing Wine. I have tried every solution that I could find, and none have worked.

```
linuxflashsandisk@LinuxFlash32GBSD:~$ sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
wine is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 50 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/15.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.6:  wine1.6 depends on wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4); however:   Package wine1.6-i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package wine1.6 (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: error processing package wine1.6-i386 (--configure):  package wine1.6-i386 is not ready for configuration  cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure. No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.                                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine:  wine depends on wine1.6 | wine1.8; however:  
  Package wine1.6 is not configured yet.
  Package wine1.8 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package wine (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving
unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.6-amd64:  wine1.6-amd64 depends on wine1.6:any (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4); however:   Package wine1.6 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package wine1.6-amd64 (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered while processing:  
 wine1.6  
 wine1.6-i386
 wine  wine1.6-amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try running ```dpkg --configure -a``` and then ```apt-get update``` just to make sure your package manager is fine, and finally you attempt to install it again.

Comment: Did what you recommended. And then did "apt-get install wine". I don't know if that was the right last step, but it didn't work.